# Eclipse JAVA VM arguments reading in properties file

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I am setting Vm argument in Eclipse like

```
-DCONFIG_DATA_PATH=Users/23760/Downloads/common_config/properties/dev
```

this value i am injecting in prop file

```
test=${CONFIG_DATA_PATH}
```

and loading that prop file using spring code

```
try {

            Properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(instancePropertiesFile);
            System.out.println(" prop " + prop.getProperty("test") +" System variable "+System.getProperty("CONFIG_DATA_PATH"));
            config.putAll(prop);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(" Error Loading the File");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

CONFIG_DATA_PATH setting successfully in system properties but its not injecting in prop file  and  `prop.getProperty("test")` is not printing the path what i want its simply print `${CONFIG_DATA_PATH}`

Comment: because one is not a `System` property?

Comment: `prop.getProperty("test")` is not system property can we inject CONFIG_DATA_PATH which is system property into properties file like test=${CONFIG_DATA_PATH}

Comment: Which aspect of this question is specific to Eclipse? To Java 8?

Comment: Does an exception get caught? If so, with what message?

Comment: @ntind No error its just prints `prop ${CONFIG_DATA_PATH} System variable Users/23760/Downloads/common_config/properties/dev`